# JQuery append not working in IE9 and JQuery 1.7.1

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer-9

I am struggling to integrate [this Bootstrap-tag](http://fdeschenes.github.io/bootstrap-tag/) plugin into my app. It is working fine with jQuery 1.8.3 as you can see it on [the GitHub project page](http://fdeschenes.github.io/bootstrap-tag/).

My application is using JQuery 1.7.1. It works great in Chrome but not in IE (not a surprise). I've spent two days now trying to understand why with no luck (I am a jQuery/JS novice).

I created a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VRk4F/1) that captures and shows this error when ran in IE 9.

The specific error is:

> SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'append'
>
> bootstrap-tag.js, line 117 character 5

And it refers to this line/code:

```
$('<span class="tag">')
  .text(value)
  .append($('<button type="button" class="close">&times;</button>')
    .on('click', function () {
      that.remove(that.element.siblings('.tag').index($(this).closest('.tag')))
    })
  )
  .insertBefore(that.element)
```

**QUESTION:**
Any idea why IE9 is complaining about the `append` not recognized?

Comment: Don't copy/paste a whole HTML document into jsFiddle. The contents of the `<body>` go into the HTML section, and JavaScript goes into the JavaScript section

Comment: Well, you're using resources that shouldn't be used that way. For example, Github files shouldn't be referenced - it's not a CDN. Luckily, if you modify the URL of raw files, it's possible). If you use proper URLs (I had to change the Prettify CSS and JS, as well as the Docs CSS URLs), IE 9 doesn't throw errors. You wouldn't have this problem if you downloaded the files and used them in a local project/server. Here's what I ended up with: http://jsfiddle.net/LbGfn/1/

Comment: Ahh yes, I forgot to change the jQuery version. Well, I'm confused, which version are you referring to? Your question says 1.7.3 (which doesn't exist), but your jsFiddle uses 1.7.1. So I would assume 1.7.1?

Comment: With 1.7.1, I see now: http://jsfiddle.net/VRk4F/1/

Comment: Dumb question, but is there any reason why you can't upgrade your version of jQuery? I know that doesn't answer the question, but 1.7.1 is quite old now anyways

Comment: I tried to upgrade to 1.10, no luck. I am still facing the same problem :(. I still would like to understand why this is happening though. More importantly, why is it working on other browsers.

Comment: Well, did you remove the 1.7.1 reference? I don't get any errors here: http://jsfiddle.net/VRk4F/3/ . I agree I'd want to know the cause, but at the same time, what does it matter? I wouldn't be surprised if it's because the versions of the resources don't match up close enough in history. I would hope that's the cause (and yeah, I don't know why it's failing specifically in IE9), but still. By the way, the demo on the Tag website doesn't even work fully because they reference invalid resource URLs

Comment: I don't see a problem with upgrading the versions of your libraries. Bootstrap can be 2.3.2 (and even 3.0 soon). jQuery can be 1.10.2. Prettify has newer versions. And Tag can use whatever it has. I like to ignore stupid errors like this when they can be solved with newer, better versions of libraries. From the Googling I did for that error, it looks like the error happens when variable names shadow element `id`s (improperly, probably). And other stupid things that IE fails on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, indeed jQuery on older versions do not return the reference to jQuery object after text() function for IE9.

Basically, the solution was not use the text function and appends the text in the creation of the span. So I changed to code bellow in bootstrap-tag.js on line 117 that solves the problem.

Follows the [JS Fiddle Solution](http://jsfiddle.net/VRk4F/5/)

Before (IE9 Buggy):

```
$('<span class="tag">')
  .text(value)
  .append($('<button type="button" class="close">&times;</button>')
    .on('click', function () {
      that.remove(that.element.siblings('.tag').index($(this).closest('.tag')))
    })
  )
  .insertBefore(that.element)
```

After (Fixed):

```
$('<span class="tag">' + value + '</span>')
    .append($('<button type="button" class="close">&times;</button>')
    .on('click', function () {
      that.remove(that.element.siblings('.tag').index($(this).closest('.tag')))
    })
  )
  .insertBefore(that.element)
```

Hope it helps.